# Magento 1.9 wysiwyg editor maxlength issue

Tags: magento-1.9

In Magento 1.9.2, I have used wysiwyg editor in my module and it  is working fine. But they have Maxlength='300'. I want to increase/remove mexlength. 
Please suggest me how can i solve this issue.

```
$fieldset->addField('description', 'editor', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('jobboard')->__('Description'),
            'class' => 'required-entry',
            'name' => 'description',
            'style'     => 'width:700px; height:500px;',
            'required' => true,
            'maxlength' => 10000,
            'config'    => Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->getConfig(),
            'wysiwyg'   => true,
        ));
```

Thank you

Comment: Please any body can help me..

Comment: Are you able to type more than 300 character.

Comment: Hello Athul, I solved it by remove 'Config' parameter. It is working fine